# When I read from tcp buffers, which number should I select for the mtu value

Tags: go, mtu

Here is my code with golang when I'm ready to read buffer:

```
func Listen() {
  listen, _ := net.Listen("tcp4", "127.0.0.1:7000")
  defer listen.Close()
  for {
    conn, _ := listen.Accept()
    go handler(&conn)
  }
}

func handler(c *net.Conn) {
  for {
    buf := make([]byte, 1464)
    n, _ := (*c).Read(buf)
    if n == 0 {
      continue
    }
  }
}
```

The 1464 is my network mtu 1492 - 28 IP Header,so which number should I input here?

My network uses ppoe protocol, so the default is (1518 - 18 - 8) 8 is ppoe protocol header, rasult is 1492, then which number should I input there 1492 or 1464?(1492-28)

Comment: Note that using the MTU size to read from a TCP stream is mostly pointless. The TCP stack reassembles the packets, and isn't something you can control. Most of the time you would want to read using the fewest number of syscalls, which is why you often wrap a connection in `bufio`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the scheme of things, 1464 vs. 1492 isn't a great deal of difference so pick the bigger one.  Maybe add a little headroom!

If you want super tight buffers of exactly the right size then do something like this

```
func handler(c *net.Conn) {
  maxSize:=1464
  for {
    buf := make([]byte, maxSize)
    n, _ := (*c).Read(buf)
    if n == 0 {
      continue
    }
    if n > maxSize {
      maxSize=n
    }
  }
```

And it will adjust.  NB make() is a relatively expensive call so you might like to look at sync.pool or other approaches to manage buffers